# Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implictly HTML Parser Python3 Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, python-3.4, html-parser

I am trying to create an HTML Parser in Python 3.4.2 on a Macbook Air(OS X):

plaintext.py:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import urllib.request, formatter, sys

website = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.profmcmillan.com")
data = website.read()
website.close()
format = formatter.AbstractFormatter(formatter.DumbWriter(sys.stdout))
ptext = HTMLParser(format)
ptext.feed(data)
ptext.close()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deannarobertazzi/Documents/plaintext.py", line 9, in <module>
    ptext.feed(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/html/parser.py", line 164, in feed
    self.rawdata = self.rawdata + data
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

I looked at the Python documentation and apparently the way you parse HTML data in Python 3 is vastly different from doing such a thing in Python 2. I don't know how to modify my code so that it works for Python 3. Thank you.

Comment: What encoding is that `data` bytestring using?  If `latin-1`, for example, `ptext.feed(data.decode('latin-1'))` would work.  It's not very different from Python 2, you just must carefully distinguish now between text (strings of Unicode characters) and byte-strings (strings of arbitrary bytes, often encoding text via various possible codecs)... which was a good idea all along but is now mandatory:-).

Comment: I included UTF-8 into the line ptext.feed(data.decode('UTF-8)) and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.x implicit conversions only worked if all the bytes were in the ascii range.[0-127]

```
>>> u'a' + 'b'
u'ab'
>>> u'a' + '\xca'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    u'a' + '\xca'
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What often happened, and why this was dropped, is that code would work when tested with ascii data, such as Prof. McMillan's site seems to be today, and later fail, such as if Prof. McMillan were to add a title with a non-ascii char, or if another source were used that were not all-ascii.

The doc for `HTMLParser.feed(data)` says that the data must be 'text', which in 3.x means a unicode string.  So bytes from the web must be decoded to unicode.   Decoding the site with `utf-8` works today because ascii is a subset of utf-8.  However, the page currently has

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

So if a non-ascii char were to be added, and the encoding not changed, `utf-8` would not work.  There is really no substitute for paying attention to encoding of bytes.  How to discover or guess the encoding of a web page (assuming that there is only one encoding used) is a separate subject.